# ios7 CameraPickerController image from camera is frozen

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller, xamarin

I have this simple code for camera View controller:

```
UIImagePickerController picker = new UIImagePickerController();
picker.PrefersStatusBarHidden ();
picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice dev = picker.CameraDevice;
PresentViewController (picker, false, null);
picker.FinishedPickingMedia += (object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e) => BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate {DismissViewController (false, null);});
```

When app starts, I can capture photo normally, but when i present picker again, camera View appears but frame(image) from previous shot is shown and frozen.  If i move my device around image doesn't change. In other words, I can use camera once but I can not use it twice. What I am doing wrong? On `iOS6` devices it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a pickerDelegate class did the trick for me. You just have to pass the current VC in the constructor so you can handle the image in your VC.

**PickerDelegate**

```
private class pickerDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
        {
            private yourVC _vc;

            public pickerDelegate (yourVC controller) : base ()
            {
                _vc = controller;
            }

            public override void FinishedPickingImage (UIImagePickerController picker, UIImage image, NSDictionary editingInfo)
            {
               //Do something whit the image
                _vc.someButton.SetBackgroundImage (image, UIControlState.Normal);

                //Dismiss the pickerVC
                picker.DismissViewController (true, null);
            }
        }
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController ();

//Set the Delegate and pass the current VC
imagePicker.Delegate = new pickerDelegate (this);
```

Comment: Thanks. Switching from Events to the Delegate model. Fixed it for me too. Here s the link that brought me here and has some additional info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20503817/383658

Comment: HI i have the same issue. i use MvvmCross picturechooser plugin. and looking at their source code they use delegate, but event the problem is still there for my app? can you guide me?

Comment: Same here. Looks like to HAVE to dismiss. Can only use the camera once on iOS 9.1