# UIImagePickerController is showing last clicked image. I am using Monotouch/Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In my project, when I launch camera first time it works fine. when I launch camera second time, I see image last clicked in view finder. I am not sure what's causing this.

Can anyone please help me here?

following is code block to launch camera:

```
        UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
        // Handle media selected.
        var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) => {
            UIImage image = (UIImage)e.Info.ObjectForKey(
                new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));

            if (image != null)
            {
                this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    this.clickedImage.Image = image;
                    image.SaveToPhotosAlbum(delegate(UIImage img, NSError err){ 
                    });
                    string pngFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine (documentsDirectory, "Photo.png"); // hardcoded filename, overwrites each time
                    NSData imgData = image.AsPNG();
                    NSError SaveErr = null;
                    if (imgData.Save(pngFilename, false, out SaveErr))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("saved as " + pngFilename);
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as" + pngFilename + " because" + SaveErr.LocalizedDescription);
                    }
                });
            }

            DismissViewController(true,null);

        };

        // Handle cancellation of picker.
        imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, e) => {
            DismissViewController(true,null);

        };



        btnCameraDisplay1.SetTitle("Take Picture", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnCameraDisplay1.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(19);
        btnCameraDisplay1.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);

        btnCameraDisplay1.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(UIImagePickerController.IsSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
            {
                imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
                imagePicker.AllowsEditing = false;
                this.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true,null);
            }
            else{
                alertView = new UIAlertView();
                alertView.AddButton("OK");
                alertView.Message = "No camera available in this device.";
                alertView.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.Default;
                alertView.Show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please post the code your are using to launch the camera control.

Comment: just attached the code above...

Comment: Need way more information. What do you mean "you see the last image clicked in the finder"? Is the code above (in it's entirety) invoked just once? Or are you calling it several times?

Comment: I have btnCameraDisplay1 button on a screen. I click the button camera is launched. after clicking photo, i select use photo and come back to my original screen from where camera is launched. Now I again click on same btnCameraDisplay1 button and this time camera is launched with last clicked image. Please let me know if you need more information around this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same Problem. Some searching here on Stackoverflow helped:

- It might be a problem with Xamarins implementation of the **FinishedPickingMedia** Event. (from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503817/383658)

Solution:
Switch from the **Event System** to **Delegates** as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035698/383658

So basically move your code from:

```
imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, e) => {}
```

to your new **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** delegates method:

```
public override void FinishedPickingMedia (UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
    {}
```